# How to sort a hash by a function depending on values from the hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, hash

I want to sort a hash by the following conditions:

1. An object that has `hash[:sold]` as `false` comes before an object that has `hash[:sold]` as `true`.
2. If both objects have `hash[:sold]` as `false enter code here`, then compute two variables `distance_a`, `distance_b` for the two hashes. I want object `a` to come before object `b` if `distance_a < distance_b`.

Code:

```
curr_hash.sort do |a,b|
  status_a = a[1][:sold]
  status_b = b[1][:sold]
  if status_a == false && status_b == false
    a_first_loc = [a[1][:loc_id], current_loc_id].min
    a_second_loc = [a[1][:loc_id], current_loc_id].max
    b_first_loc = [b[1][:loc_id], current_loc_id].min
    b_second_loc = [b[1][:loc_id], current_loc_id].max
    distance_a = LocationDistance.find_by(city_id: current_city.id, loc_a: a_first_loc, loc_b: a_second_loc).distance
    distance_b = LocationDistance.find_by(city_id: current_city.id, loc_a: b_first_loc, loc_b: b_second_loc).distance
    distance_a <=> distance_b
  else return status_a == false ? 1 : 0
  end
end
```

Comment: Is not clear the problem you have and question is malformed.

Comment: distance_a and distance_b are a function of loc_id obtained from the hash. I want to use these two values to sort the hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowing @Maxim's `distance` function and using `sort_by` means the distance is only calculated once for each item.

Extracting `distance` as a function also has the advantage that it can be tested independently

```
def distance(hash)
  LocationDistance.find_by(loc_a: hash[1][:loc_id], current_loc_id].min,
                           loc_b: [hash[1][:loc_id], current_loc_id].max,
                           city_id: current_city.id).distance
end

a.sort_by(|x| [true ? 1 : 0, distance(x)])
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do the job nicely for you:

```
def distance(hash)
  LocationDistance.find_by(loc_a: hash[1][:loc_id], current_loc_id].min,
                           loc_b: [hash[1][:loc_id], current_loc_id].max,
                           city_id: current_city.id).distance
end

a.sort{|a,b| a[:sold] == b[:sold] ? ((distance(a) < distance(b)) ? -1 : 1) : (a[:sold] ? 1 : -1)}
```